# Please how do I get ABI of my token after deploying on BSCMAINET

Tags: token, blockchain, bep20, bscscan

I deployed a contract on bscscan recent using remix but I forgot to copy the abi code...
Please how can I get it back...
I need to communicate with the contract using web3
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ABI` link in the Remix `Solidity compiler` tab. It will copy the ABI JSON of the currently selected source code to your clipboard.

[image: Remix screenshot]